# Error: Unnecessary use of boolean literals in conditional expression

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I am trying this code with ESLint

Code snippet:

```
if (disableFutureDates) {
    return isActiveDate < 0 ? true : false; //error
  }
```

Got this ESLint error: error Unnecessary use of boolean literals in conditional expression.

Comment: `return isActiveDate < 0` - this already returns a boolean, you don't need to explicitly returns a boolean value using a ternary operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the result of the condition. The comparison returns a boolean value.

```
return isActiveDate < 0;
```